# Differences between subprocess module, envoy, sarge and pexpect?

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect, python-envoy

I am thinking about making a program that will need to send input and take output from the various aircrack-ng suite tools. I know of a couple of python modules like subprocess, envoy, sarge and pexpect that would provide the necessary functionality. Can anyone advise on what I should be using or not using, especially as I'm new to python.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't heard of most of those libraries, but in general if there's a standard module that does everything I need, I'd favor it over any 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: You may need `pexpect` instead of `subprocess` when you want bidirectional communication with a process. I don't know the other two libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the maintainer of `sarge`, I can tell you that its goals are broadly similar to `envoy` (in terms of ease of use over `subprocess`) and there is (IMO) more functionality in `sarge` with respect to:

- Cross-platform support for bash-like syntax (e.g.use of `&&`, `||`, `&` in command lines)
- Better support for capturing `subprocess` output streams and working with them asynchronously
- More documentation, especially about the internals and peripheral issues like threading+forking in the context of using subprocess
- Support for prevention of shell injection attacks

Of course YMMV, but you can check out [the docs](http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), they're reasonably comprehensive.

Comment: Testing sarge vs envoy (I am replacing pexpect to add windows support to my application), I found that envoy uses shlex.This results in native windows paths not being supported (shlex removes "\" chars). This can be worked around (when using pathlib) by calling [as_posix()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) before passing paths to envoy. However, sarge works with windows paths out-of-the-box.

Comment: Sarge has unfortunately not been updated since 2018 (about two years stale now), and was left in "beta" stage. It otherwise looked promising!

Comment: @Andy as the maintainer of `sarge` I still respond to feature requests and bug reports where feasible - there have no updates since 2018 since it does what I need and there have been no bug reports or feature requests that I can progress.

Comment: @VinaySajip it sounds like you no longer consider to be "beta" then. Would you care to make a non-beta release?

Comment: @Andy was released on 24 Aug 2020: https://pypi.org/project/sarge/0.1.6/

Answer (score 4):

### pexpect

In 2015, pexpect does not work on windows. Rumored to add "experimental" support [in the next version](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/17), but this has been a rumor for a long time (I'm not holding my breath).

Having written many applications using pexpect (and loving it), I am now sorry because one of the things I love about python (that it is cross platform) is not true for my applications.

If you plan to ever add windows support, for the moment, avoid pexpect.

### envoy

Not much activity in the last year. And few commits (12 total) since 2012. Not very promising for its future.

Internally it uses shlex in a way that is not compatible with windows paths (the commands must use '/' not '\' for directory separators). A workaround (when using pathlib) is to call [as_posix()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) on path objects before passing them as commands. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811981/880509).

Getting access to the internal streams (i.e. I want to parse the output to have some updating scrollbars), seems possible but is not documented.

### sarge

Works on windows out-of-the-box and has an expect() method that should provide functionality similar to pexpect (allowing me to update a scrollbar). Recent activity, but it is hosted on [gitlab](https://github.com/vsajip/sarge) and [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/sarge/) (very confusing).

## Personal Conclusion

I'm moving *from* **pexpect** *to* **sarge** for future development. Seems to provide similar feature set to pexpect and supports windows.

Comment: So what about `subprocess`? It still works, it just has annoying syntax. And it works on all platforms, unlike some of these others.

Answer (score 2):

**subprocess** - is a standard library module, so it'll be available with python installation. But it has a reputation of hard to use since it's api is non-intuitive.

**envoy** - is a third party module that wraps around subprocess. It was written to be an easy to use alternative to subprocess. The author of envoy Kenneth Reitz is famous for his [Python for Humans](http://python-for-humans.heroku.com/) philosophy.

I'm not familiar with the other two.