# `envoy`-like abstraction of subprocess

Tags: python, python-envoy

I was really excited about the [Envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) project when I first heard about it. Having a sane API for `subprocess` is something I very much need.

However, `envoy` seems not to be maintained anymore. The last commit was made 10 months ago, and the last release was made 2 years ago. There are a bunch of serious bugs in it that I reported a long time ago, but were not fixed.

I'm looking for an alternative. Does anyone know of a Python package that does the same thing as Envoy (gives a good API to subprocess), except it's actively maintained?

Comment: I'd ask the maintainer why he stopped working on envoy.

Comment: I asked him whether he's aware of any alternatives, but he ignored me.

Comment: "Ignoring" is a strong word -- many authors of popular things tend to get busy and overloaded with work. Give it time.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I emailed him two weeks ago. He might answer someday, but I wouldn't hold my breath. I could have used a happier word than "ignoring" but I find that using happy words to describe a sad reality doesn't really make the reality happier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `sarge` package, available with: `pip install sarge`

It is documented here: http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation-and-testing

It seems to be actively maintained & the maintainer is a frequent user of stack overflow (see one of their posts on the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032170/2942522 )

A snippet from the `sarge` docs & one of the usage examples provided:

"If you want to interact with external programs from your Python applications, Sarge is a library which is intended to make your life easier than using the subprocess module in Python’s standard library."

```
>>> from sarge import run, Capture
>>> p = run('echo foo; echo bar; echo baz', stdout=Capture())
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'foo\n'
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'bar\n'
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'baz\n'
>>> p.stdout.readline()
''
```

Comment: The API is not as nice as `envoy`, but at least it's maintained. Answer accepted.